# Using external library in react-native + expo

Tags: android, react-native, expo

There is a working android app developed at React-Native + Expo. It is necessary either to add third-party libraries to this application (for example, OpenCV), or to configure its interaction with another file (for example, Python), which implements the necessary logic. (You need to send data, process it with a python script, send the result back)

It is important that the application does not have access to the Internet.

Please tell me the best way to solve this problem

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

If you can't access an API through network, your best (and only?) bet might be to use a tool that handles cross-compilation of Python to JavaScript.

I've never tried it but this one claims to do exactly this: http://www.transcrypt.org